# More sound approach to designing a spline functor?

Tags: pointers, rust, unsafe, type-safety

I have made the following definition of a spline data structure:

```rs
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct BSpline
{
    knots: Vec<f32>,
    control_points: Vec<Vec3>,
    /// Internal helper variable. Used to optimize repetetitive samplings on close
    /// $t$ values.
    last_t_index: usize,
    order: usize,
}

impl BSpline
{
    pub fn sample(&self, t: f32) -> Vec3
    {
        debug_assert!(self.control_points.len() >= self.order);

        let t = f32::clamp(t, self.knots[0], *self.knots.last().unwrap());

        let mut t_index = self.last_t_index;
        while !(t >= self.knots[t_index] && t <= self.knots[t_index + 1])
        {
            t_index = (t_index + 1) % self.knots.len();
        }

        // TODO(low): find a better way than this hack.
        let ptr = &self.last_t_index as *const usize as *mut usize;
        unsafe {
            ptr.write(usize::min(t_index, self.order - 1));
        };
        // Create the cache to compute the pyramid of intermediate evaluations.
        let order = self.order;
        let degree = order - 1;
        let mut evaluation = Vec::new();

        for i in 0..order
        {
            evaluation.push(self.control_points[t_index - degree + i]);
        }

        for l in 0..degree
        {
            for j in ((l + 1)..=degree).rev()
            {
                let alpha = (t - self.knots[t_index - degree + j])
                    / (self.knots[t_index - l + j] - self.knots[t_index - degree + j]);
                evaluation[j] = (1.0 - alpha) * evaluation[j - 1] + alpha * evaluation[j];
            }
        }

        evaluation[degree]
    }
}
```

Note the absolutely awful hack I needed to do to make the sample method take a reference rather than a mutable reference. Which of course makes the entire data structure unsound.

The reasons the hack:

- I need to compute a lot of differential operators on the spline, which are defined generically, defining these operators to take FnMut instead of Fn leads to a lot of superflous cloning which is problematic.
- I need this to be fast, I don't want the overhead from a mutex or even from an atomic boolean check.
- UnsafeCells are not clonable.

The code is intended to be used in single threaded code only, and in that case this should work ok, but it's still a red flag. Is there something I can do to improve it?

Comment: This absolutely awful hack is not just absolutely awful: it's UB.

Comment: Is it UB? I think it's just unsound. Why would this be UB ina single threaded context, rust does allow you to write through pointers, where is the UB being invoked?

Comment: Writing to a pointer obtained from a shared reference is always UB. There is absolutely no way to write to a shared reference without `UnsafeCell`, period.

Comment: Rust allows writing through pointers, but it doesn't allow mutation of immutable bytes, everything reached through a shared reference or derived from it is considered immutable bytes, so writing through a pointer derived from a shared reference is UB. See [Behavior considered undefined](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html)

Comment: @Makogan being unsound and being UB are synonyms. If something is unsound it is because it produces UB

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze not quite, you can write unsound code that never invokes UB. For example a safe function which performs uncheked reads into a slice is unsound, but unless you actually read past the end of the slice it's not UB. In other words unsound code can be used to invoke UB from safe Rust, but it's not necesarily always UB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make `last_t_index` a [`Cell<usize>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html). It provides interior mutability, is `Clone`-able, and has no runtime overhead. It does this by requiring that the `.get()` and `.set()` methods *copy* the value, but for `usize` that is of no concern.